# How to register a Web Core API with App Registration in Azure

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API requiring to be protected in relation to utilising OAuth-2.0 with a client and secret, for multiple companies.

I have seen some threads suggesting to create this under `Azure > App Registration` but some of the steps are new/obsolete and not sure the correct way to set this up (for example i was supposed to add a role but that no longer exists)

Does anyone know the correct steps to take to register an app on Azure and then set the secret etc for use with my Core API app?

Comment: Have you tried with any of the code, if yes, please share the code.

Comment: What code? I was asking for the steps to register the app at first?

Answer (score 0):

***Check the below steps to register Web Core API Application in Azure Active Directory.***

- First, we need to register the Application and get the `Client` and `Tenant ID` details from `Azure Active Directory`.

[image]

[image]

- The no. of App registrations depends on the no. of applications you are using.
- Need to create separate app registrations for both `API` and `Client App`.
- We can add the Redirect URL later also, after creating the Web API in local.
- Navigate to the newly created App and add the `Redirect URI`.

[image]

- Click on `Add a Paltform` => select `Web`

[image]

- As suggested in the below Image, select the `implicit options` based on your requirement.

[image]

- As it is a `Web API App`, we need to set few configurations in the registered App => `Expose an API`.

[image]

[image]

- This App ID URI serves as a resource identifier when we access this Application for getting the token.
- To use, delegated permissions we need to add the scope.

> for example i was supposed to add a role but that no longer exists

We can find the option to add an app role in `APP roles` section.

[image]

***Configurations for the Registered Client App:***

Provide the permissions for the client app to access the API.

- In `API Permissions`, click on `Add a permission` => select `Microsoft Graph` => select the permissions based on the requirement of your Application(Delegated or Application).

[image]

- If you have already deployed your API, it can be found in the `My API's`.

[image]

- Now, create a new client secret and make a note of that value, need to be included it in the Application Configuration to authenticate the App.

[image]

[image]